# Problem with Samsung Galaxy calls

Tags: samsung, speaker

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Active mobile phone and for the past year suddenly I couldn't make a call. Whenever I was trying to answer or call someone I couldn't hear them and they couldn't hear me. I tried fixing it alone but I didn't make it. So I went to someone more expert. He changed the microphone and the speaker but still. The problem is still there. Now sometimes it works but suddenly stops. The weird thing is that on Viber I can hear and they can hear me. 
Also, tried to change the sim card but still. No solution. 
Has anyone had a problem like that ?